# jquery validation plugin detects errors, but no messages appear, why not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formvalidation-plugin

I'm using the [jQuery Validator](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin 1.19.5 on a slightly large (but simple) form generated from a PDF by an [online converter to html5](https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdfform-to-html5-converter)

The form has a Submit button implemented as a button with onclick to a javascript function within the `formviewer.js` file that is part of the conversion to html5. If I open the form in Chrome 107.0.5304.107 Developer Tools, I can see that the Submit button goes to the following code that I added to the `success` branch of the function that handles the submit in `formviewer.js`:

```
            success: function() {
                const OSHform=$("form").eq(0);
                if (OSHform.valid()) {
                    top.document.location.href = "/Adsentry/completed";
                }
                else {
                    alert("Fields did not validate, please fix errors and try again");
                }
            },
            failure: function() {
                alert("Form failed to submit, please try again")
            }
```

In a separate script, I invoked validate() on the form element, passing it rules for the fields to validate.

```
var $j = jQuery;
var OSHform = $j("form");
OSHform.validate({
   rules: {
     "NAME OF DRIVER": "required",
     "EMAIL": "required",
     "EMAIL": "email",
     "ADDRESS": "required"
   }
 });
```

If I omit required fields, or enter an invalid email address in an email field, the call to valid() returns false. And in fact, if I look at the input elements in the Elements tab, I can see that `class="error"` gets added, and if I correct the error it changes to class="valid". Additionally, with `class="error"`, a label gets added for that element, also with `class="error"`, and correcting the problem adds style="display:none;" to the label.

So everything is great, except that there is no text or message that goes with the label, so its presence/absence, or the presence/absence of `display:none` on it, has no effect on the normal display of the page.

I have tried stepping through the code in the debugger, but I'm afraid my javascript is so weak I can't really figure out what's going on to the extent of understanding why the messages are not being displayed.

You can play with it live [here](https://www.onesourcehorse.com/Adsentry/combineddriving) for the time being, but I can't promise to stop fiddling with it! There are currently only 3 required fields: Name of driver, Address, and Email. If they are all correct, the form submits as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little disappointed that this didn't even get any comments, let alone answers. On the other hand, it turned out the answer was exactly as anyone even slightly more experienced than me would likely have guessed: errors were being reported in HTML elements, but there was no CSS to put them in the right location on the page. The plugin seemed to be buggy in failing to produce default message text describing the errors; instead, it just produced message text that was simply the name attribute of the erroneous input element. But without appropriate CSS, that name attribute was output in the black strip at the bottom of the page, making it essentially invisible. It took a sharp eye to notice the sudden appearance of "fly specs" at the bottom of the page when clicking the submit button.

The plugin just inserts an HTML element into the DOM immediately following the bad input element. But the files generated from the PDF include a style sheet with selectors using the ID of each input element to give the input element absolute placement on the page. And simply inserting an element into the DOM as the next sibling of the input element, without a style, results in having it rendered at the bottom of the page. Even when I figured out that the lack of CSS was the problem, it took me a while to get something that worked: good old selector specificity in action. All of the input elements were placed using ID selectors with absolute position, and I could find no way to have the simple next-sibling relationship of the message to the input element cause the message to be rendered immediately after the input element. Although it made me feel "icky" to do it, the solution I came up with was to use jQuery to iterate over all the message elements with the "error" class, get the ID of the input element it was reporting, and then use $.css() to get the input element's effective *top*, *left*, and *width* style attributes. Then strip off the trailing "px", multiply by 1 to get a numeric value, add the *width* to the *left* numeric value, and specify new *top* and *left* attributes using $.css() on the message elements. This put the messages I defined in the *messages* sub-object of the object passed to the *validate* constructor appear in the right locations. It only remains a mystery why the default messages didn't appear instead of the names of the input elements for elements that were invalid.

Comment: I guess maybe it wasn't a bug that the plugin just displayed the "name" attribute of each required element that lacked a value. I suppose that's a reasonable but pithy way to say that the element with that name needed a value.